# Gradle doesn't run tests without the "clean" or "--rerun-tasks" options

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests

I'm trying to run automated tests for an Android project via the command line. However, `gradlew test` doesn't execute any tests unless I use `gradlew clean test` or `gradlew test --rerun-tasks`. Running `gradlew test -i` shows the following message:

`Skipping task 'app:test' as it has no actions`

I was able to run `gradlew test` without problems when I worked on another project for a previous job. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this due to differences between Gradle versions?

This isn't a big deal, except `gradlew clean test` and `gradlew test --rerun-tasks` take much longer to run.